# How to let user input in a input field and convert it into html code?

Tags: javascript, html, forum

I am new to the website building. I see there is one function in many forums(including stack overflow) which is converting user inputs into html, like the following screenshot.

[This is just an example from community.fabric.microsoft.com](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AwLcY.jpg)

The key point is user just typing in regular text and format it like Word (for bold, underline.., add pictures).....then these input will be converted into relevant html code automatically.

How to achieve it by using Javascript or other programming languages or any frameworks..?

Thanks

Some details of how to achieve it.

Comment: Google for code on implementing an editor.  There are dozens around.  If you cant find any, then ask on Software Recommendations